# ORDER BY NULL slower than ORDER BY column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-optimization

according to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html), adding ORDER BY NULL after GROUP BY should "*avoid the overhead of sorting the result*". If so, why is following query aprox 5 times slower

```
SELECT COUNT(*) advert_count, category.name
FROM advert
LEFT JOIN category ON advert.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE (
advert.state_id = 2
)
GROUP BY advert.category_id
ORDER BY NULL
LIMIT 5
```

than query with `ORDER BY advert_count`?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) advert_count, category.name
FROM advert
LEFT JOIN category ON advert.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE (
advert.state_id = 2
)
GROUP BY advert.category_id
ORDER BY advert_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

From phpMyAdmin profiling:
1st query:

```
Sorting for group   -
Sorting result      0.000002
Sending data        12.069774
```

2nd query:

```
Sorting for group   2.436986
Sorting result      0.000028
Sending data        0.000021
```

I am confused by this, could anyone explain me what is going on there?

Comment: How often did you run the test?

Comment: I'am also confused. As I can see, the first query is faster!?

Comment: Maybe it the case of indexes? What you get if EXPLAIN those queries?

Comment: Interesting. Possibly there is an index on `advert_count`, speeding up the query. Care to post the `EXPLAIN` results? (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)

Comment: @cularis I've tried it at least 10 times with same results.

Comment: @Piskvor There is not index on advert_count since it's just alias for COUNT(*) but I can post the EXPLAIN results anyway.

Comment: This is just a guess, but could the `ORDER BY NULL` be affecting the `JOIN` by suppressing sorting on `category_id`?

Comment: you should avoid phpmyadmin, try directly console into mysql using mysql build-in client?

Comment: when COUNT(*) is used InnoDB **ALWAYS* does a full table scan as the rows are ordered by the index and not by the row number like MyISAM. So the index IS NOT used in this case even if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY NULL` is not ordering by anything at all.  Every record gets the same position.

So the first query is selecting the first 5 groups found in the data.  But the second query is calculating the results for all groups in the data, and finding the top 5 based on the count.

This is born out by the first two overheads you have shown.

The 3rd overhead is the difference - Sending Data.  For a non-database related reason, when you ran it it took a long time to transfer the data.  This is likely due to server or network load at that moment in time.

Comment: I would say the same, but I've run the queries more than 10 times with the same results and the profiler shows very similar values and everytime is the second query much faster.